# CMake Project not loading on WSL2 via Visual Studio 2022

Tags: linux, visual-studio, cmake, cpprest-sdk

I am using Visual Studio 2022 preview.

I am trying to Compile and Run [Cpprest](https://github.com/Tushar-Harsora/SecureChatServer) based Project on WSL2 Debian Distribution.
I have CMake v3.21.2 in Debian installed.

the project builds and runs on bare linux system as there is already `Dockerfile` present in project directory and tested by me.

while opening project in Visual Studio i get following Error in `Cross Platform Logging` window and i am not able to build and run the project.

it says file `.vs/SecureChatServer/out/build/linux-default/.cmake/api/v1/query/client-MicrosoftVS/query.json` in WSL2 Distribution does not exist

```
15:17:34.6074634 [Info, Thread 86]  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.ParseCache: ClearSingleConfigurationAsync: Clearing cache entry for CMakeLists.txt.
15:17:34.6530612 [Info, Thread 93]  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.Services.BuildProjectScannerService: Starting scan ...
15:17:34.7459086 [Info, Thread 93]  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.Services.BuildProjectScannerService: Scanner Parsing starting: projectfilepath CMakeLists.txt FileScanType: System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[System.Type,System.Object] Config Name:linux-default
15:17:34.8382805 [Info, Thread 84]  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.ParseCache: CacheGenerationStarted root: CMAKELISTS.TXTlinux-default CMakeLists.txt linux-default
15:17:34.8472770 [Info, Thread 84]  Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Linux.Project.RemoteCMakeParser: RemoteCMakeParser ctor
15:17:34.8472770 [Info, Thread 84]  libcmake.Linux.RemoteCMakeParser: RemoteCMakeParser ctor
15:17:34.8472770 [Info, Thread 84]  Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Linux.Project.RemoteCMakeParser: RemoteCMakeParser finished
15:17:34.8482814 [Info, Thread 84]  libcmake.Linux.RemoteCMakeUtils: RemoteCMakeCopyFilesStarted Copying source directory 'C:\Users\Tushar\Downloads\Semester 7\MP\SecureChatServer\' to destination directory '/home/tushar/.vs/SecureChatServer' on '' (method=rsync).
15:17:35.1282745 [Info, Thread 11]  libcmake.Linux.IO.DirectoryScan: Scan time: 79
15:17:35.1552754 [Info, Thread 11]  libcmake.Linux.IO.DirectoryScan: Compare time: 26
15:17:35.1992766 [Info, Thread 11]  libcmake.Linux.RemoteCMakeUtils: RemoteCMakeCopyFilesFinished Finished copying files (elapsed time 00h:00m:00s:200ms).
15:17:35.3902747 [Info, Thread 52]  libcmake.Linux.RemoteCMakeParser: ParseAsync
15:17:35.3912810 [Info, Thread 52]  libcmake.Linux.RemoteCMakeParser: CreateCMakeDaemonAsync
15:17:35.3912810 [Info, Thread 52]  libcmake.Linux.RemoteCMakeParameters: Connecting to the remote system
15:17:35.5384620 [Info, Thread 52]  libcmake.Linux.RemoteCMakeParameters: Connected to the remote system
15:17:35.6864045 [Info, Thread 14]  libcmake.CMakeDaemonDriver: CMake version parsed: True, input string: cmake version 3.21.2, matched version: 3.21.2.0
15:17:35.6883976 [Info, Thread 14]  libcmake.Linux.RemoteCMakeParameters: CMake version '3.21.2.0' identified on the remote
15:17:35.8373996 [Info, Thread 9]   libcmake.Linux.RemoteCMakeParameters: Found cmake executable at /usr/local/bin/cmake.
15:17:36.0284001 [Info, Thread 14]  libcmake.CMakeDaemonDriver: CMake version parsed: True, input string: cmake version 3.21.2, matched version: 3.21.2.0
15:17:36.0304011 [Info, Thread 14]  libcmake.Linux.RemoteCMakeParser: CreateCMakeDaemonAsync done
15:17:36.0304011 [Info, Thread 14]  libcmake.CMakeListsParser: Parsing without cache
15:17:36.1454044 [Info, Thread 14]  libcmake.CMakeDaemonDriver: CMake version parsed: True, input string: cmake version 3.21.2, matched version: 3.21.2.0
15:17:36.1484013 [Info, Thread 14]  libcmake.Linux.RemoteFileApiDaemon: CMake version '3.21.2.0' identified on the remote
15:17:36.1854036 [Error, Thread 14] Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Project.ExternalBuildProject.ProjectProvider: liblinux.IO.IOException: Failed to get permissions for file '/home/tushar/.vs/SecureChatServer/out/build/linux-default/.cmake/api/v1/query/client-MicrosoftVS/query.json'. ---> liblinux.IO.IOException: Failed to get permissions for file '/home/tushar/.vs/SecureChatServer/out/build/linux-default/.cmake/api/v1/query/client-MicrosoftVS/query.json'.
   at liblinux.Local.IO.WindowsSubsystemFileSystem.StatPath(String remotePath, String format, String error)
   at liblinux.Local.IO.WindowsSubsystemFileSystem.GetPermissions(String remotePath)
   at liblinux.IO.RemoteFileSystemInfo..ctor(IRemoteFileSystem fs, String remotePath)
   at liblinux.Local.IO.WindowsSubsystemFileSystem.UploadFile(String localFileName, String remoteFileName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at liblinux.Local.IO.WindowsSubsystemFileSystem.UploadFile(String localFileName, String remoteFileName)
   at liblinux.Local.IO.WindowsSubsystemFileSystem.UploadFileAsync(String localFileName, String remoteFileName, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at libcmake.Linux.RemoteFileApiDaemon.<WriteQueryFileAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at libcmake.Linux.RemoteFileApiDaemon.<GenerateCacheAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at libcmake.CMakeListsParser.<ParseImplAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at libcmake.Linux.RemoteCMakeParser.<ParseAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Linux.Project.RemoteCMakeParser.<ParseAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Project.ExternalBuildProject.ProjectProvider.<ParseProjectAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
15:17:36.1854036 [Error, Thread 14] Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.ParseCache: Unknown exception during cache generation: root: CMAKELISTS.TXTlinux-default CMakeLists.txt linux-default
15:17:36.1864019 [Error, Thread 36] Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.ParseCache: liblinux.IO.IOException: Failed to get permissions for file '/home/tushar/.vs/SecureChatServer/out/build/linux-default/.cmake/api/v1/query/client-MicrosoftVS/query.json'. ---> liblinux.IO.IOException: Failed to get permissions for file '/home/tushar/.vs/SecureChatServer/out/build/linux-default/.cmake/api/v1/query/client-MicrosoftVS/query.json'.
   at liblinux.Local.IO.WindowsSubsystemFileSystem.StatPath(String remotePath, String format, String error)
   at liblinux.Local.IO.WindowsSubsystemFileSystem.GetPermissions(String remotePath)
   at liblinux.IO.RemoteFileSystemInfo..ctor(IRemoteFileSystem fs, String remotePath)
   at liblinux.Local.IO.WindowsSubsystemFileSystem.UploadFile(String localFileName, String remoteFileName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at liblinux.Local.IO.WindowsSubsystemFileSystem.UploadFile(String localFileName, String remoteFileName)
   at liblinux.Local.IO.WindowsSubsystemFileSystem.UploadFileAsync(String localFileName, String remoteFileName, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at libcmake.Linux.RemoteFileApiDaemon.<WriteQueryFileAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at libcmake.Linux.RemoteFileApiDaemon.<GenerateCacheAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at libcmake.CMakeListsParser.<ParseImplAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at libcmake.Linux.RemoteCMakeParser.<ParseAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Linux.Project.RemoteCMakeParser.<ParseAsync>d__29.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Project.ExternalBuildProject.ProjectProvider.<ParseProjectAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Project.ExternalBuildProject.ProjectProvider.<ParseProjectAsync>d__33.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.ParseCache.<ParseAsyncImpl>d__34.MoveNext()
15:17:36.1904000 [Info, Thread 46]  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.Services.BuildProjectScannerService: Scanner Parsing done: projectfilepath CMakeLists.txt FileScanType: System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary`2[System.Type,System.Object] Config Name:linux-default
15:17:36.1924027 [Info, Thread 53]  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.Services.BuildProjectScannerService: Compute file data values for CMakeLists.txt Config linux-default
15:17:36.1943992 [Error, Thread 113]    Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.Services.BuildProjectScannerService: FDV Error for CMakeLists.txt Config linux-default Canceled False AutoGenerateCanceled False
15:17:36.2074002 [Info, Thread 107] Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.Services.BuildProjectScannerService: OnFileScannerCompleted for CMakeLists.txt
15:17:36.2084013 [Info, Thread 107] Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workspace.ExternalBuildFramework.Impl.Services.BuildProjectScannerService: Finishing scan.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution to problem is manually creating the `query.json` file at location

`$HOME/.vs/$PROJECT_NAME/out/build/linux-default/.cmake/api/v1/query/client-MicrosoftVS/query.json`

the content of the query.json should be

```
{
   "requests":[
      {
         "kind":"cache",
         "version":2
      },
      {
         "kind":"cmakeFiles",
         "version":1
      },
      {
         "kind":"codemodel",
         "version":2
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Have a look at line 24 of the log you pasted. VS failed to get permissions on the `query.json` file. Another way to fix the issue, then, would be to check permissions on that working tree: `Microsoft.VisualStudio.CMake.Project.ExternalBuildProject.ProjectProvider: liblinux.IO.IOException: Failed to get permissions for file '/home/tushar/.vs/SecureChatServer/out/build/linux-default/.cmake/api/v1/query/client-MicrosoftVS/query.json'.`

Comment: @rturrado yes i have seen that line in the log. but thing is that i checked that directory and `client-MicrosoftVS` was empty and no `query.json` that folder was owned and readable/writable by user `tushar` and whole source tree seemed fine. what i think problem was that Visual Studio or CMake Extension `stat`s  for the file without checking if it exists. and when you `stat` file that doesn't exist its `IOException` and Message `Failed to get permissions for file ...` means when Code tried to get permissions the file was not found thus could not get Permissions.

Comment: Ah, cool, yes, you may be right there, I hadn't thought about it that way. Since the file doesn't exist, VS complains of having failed to get permissions for it. Whenever I see this type of errors, and more when we mix operating systems accessing a same file system, I tend to think the problem comes from a permission issue. Double check though that what you tell me about read/write permissions is both true for Windows and WSL2 (e.g. from a Windows `cmd` and a Debian `console`).